# ggplot geom_boxplot for gene expression data

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I am trying to get boxplots for 4 different genes with the expression data for each gene across multiple patients.

I've tried multiple ways and just keep hitting errors. I can do it using the base boxplot() function, but can't figure it out in ggplot and I can't see anywhere to help - spent hours reading other answers and questions yesterday! Mostly all other data seems to be as 2 columns so can specify x = column a and y = column b. However, I want to plot all 4 columns of my entire df and I couldn't find any help with that. I can do one at a time in ggplot but not all 4 together.

**The data I have, BCON_sig_genes, is 4 genes each with values between 3-6 for 152 samples. The df is 152 obs of 4 variables, where the 4 columns are headed each of the gene names and all the cells are values as shown below.**

```
         CD3E      LAT    ZAP70      LCK
```

1002 4.214679 5.652482 4.788204 5.393783

1022 4.424925 5.776641 4.864269 5.593587

8035 4.327270 5.725364 4.509920 4.961659

8037 4.415715 5.494048 4.435241 5.081846

9004 4.290078 5.265329 4.799106 5.275424

9005 4.233490 5.338098 4.666506 5.069394

*The following code gets me one gene at a time, by substituting in the name of the gene.*

`BCON_sig_genes %>%  ggplot(aes(y = CD3E, x = "CD3E"))+ geom_boxplot()`

[ggplot boxplot 1 gene only](https://i.stack.imgur.com/edZbU.png)
*I have tried `gene <- colnames(BCON_sig_genes)` and then inputting x = gene but it doesn't work and comes up with the following error message:*

Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (152): x

I think I need to sort out what y is. I tried leaving blank so it would take all the data and sort for each column but no luck.

**I tried using a gather() function and making key and value but I couldn't quite figure it out without getting errors... but this felt like I was on the right track!**

With the base function all I have to do it `boxplot(BCON_sig_genes)` and it just plots all 4 genes on a graph with the correct values. [base function boxplot all genes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UC7D4.png)

I think I need to wrangle the data better for ggplot so I can tell it that y is just all the expression values for each column but I'm not sure how.

Any help would be much appreciated!!

Thanks, Vicky

Comment: Can you provide a mock data frame and possibly an image of the graph you want to produce?

Comment: Welcome to SO! As @KotaMori said, please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Also, it sounds like you maybe want to store your data as [tidy data](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/tidy-data.html)

Comment: Hi, I've edited the post now to show head of the data frame and the 2 boxplots I can currently produce! Hope that's a bit clearer now? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For ggplot to work, you need to get the data in a long format. Which basically means you get the gene names in column 1 and their expression in column 2. You had the right idea with gather but gather is being replaced with pivot_longer.

```
 library(tidyverse)

data %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = CD3E:LCK, 
               names_to = "gene", 
               values_to = "expression") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = gene,
             y = expression)) +
  geom_boxplot()
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I was hoping I was on the right track I just couldn't quite get there! That worked perfectly. You've helped me so much.

Comment: Happy to help! Good luck